# Login code for Django

Tags: django

Can anyone give me some sample code with a template code to create a Django login?

Thanks.

Comment: not a real question. ask what you need and show us what you've got, easier to help then

Answer (score 2):

A sample login template is included [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views): 
Take a look at that entire page, it includes demo code and a complete walkthrough.