# In Django, how do I know the currently logged-in user?

Tags: django, authentication

In Django, how do I know the currently logged-in user?

Comment: Duplicate of your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476596/login-code-for-django

Comment: @Abizem, no that is not a duplicate of this question at all.

Answer (score 117):

Where do you need to know the user?

In **[views](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-in-web-requests)** the user is provided in the request as `request.user`.

For user-handling in **templates** see [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-data-in-templates)

If you want to save the creator or editor of a **model's instance** you can do something like:

model.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='created_by')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    edited_by  = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='edited_by')
    edited_on  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    published  = models.BooleanField(default=None)
```

admin.py

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields= ('title','slug','text','category','published')
    inlines = [ImagesInline]
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change): 
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        if not hasattr(instance,'created_by'):
            instance.created_by = request.user
        instance.edited_by = request.user
        instance.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return instance

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change): 

        def set_user(instance):
            if not instance.created_by:
                instance.created_by = request.user
            instance.edited_by = request.user
            instance.save()

        if formset.model == Article:
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            map(set_user, instances)
            formset.save_m2m()
            return instances
        else:
            return formset.save()
```

I found this on the Internet, but I don't know where anymore

Comment: Just a note, in save_formset -> set_user, it should be if not hasattr(instance,'created_by')

Comment: can I get the current user in settings.py?

Comment: Why would you do that? (please create a new question, my django days are long gone)

Comment: @vikingosegundo I was just wondering why you don't use Django anymore? Don't you do back-end development anymore or have you moved on to NodeJS?

Comment: I am currently working exclusively as an iOS developer, but from time to time for prototyping purposes Django is still the weapon of choice for me.

Comment: for some reason it didn't work for me using the inner function `set_user` and then mapping it through `instances`. It just didn't save new models into database. I had to use a `for instance in instances:`  with the `set_user` body inside the loop and worked perfectly. Additionally, I think the `if formset.model == Article` should be `if formset.model == Image`. Thanks @vikingosegundo for your answer. I was hitting my head to the keyboard for days trying to solve this!!

Answer (score 8):

Extending @vikingosegundo's answer, if you want to get the username inside Models, I found a way that involves declaring a MiddleWare. Create a file called `get_username.py` inside your app, with this content:

```
from threading import current_thread

_requests = {}

def get_username():
    t = current_thread()
    if t not in _requests:
         return None
    return _requests[t]

class RequestMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        _requests[current_thread()] = request
```

Edit your `settings.py` and add it to the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'yourapp.get_username.RequestMiddleware',
)
```

Now, in your `save()` method, you can get the current username like this:

```
from get_username import get_username

...

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    req = get_username()
    print "Your username is: %s" % (req.user)
```

Comment: Dedicated thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991460/django-get-current-user-in-model-save

Comment: @nKn is the really dedicated MiddleWare necessary to invoke `get_username()` in `Models` object? If so, it would be nice to have a link to a canonical docs regarding that. Are there updated native django functions in 1.9.5 to do the same?

Answer (score 7):

**Django 1.9.6 default project has `user` in the default templates**

So you can write things like this directly:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {{ user.username }}
{% else %}
    Not logged in.
{% endif %}
```

This functionality is provided by the`django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` context processor in `settings.py`.

Dedicated template question: [How to access the user profile in a Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422140/how-to-access-the-user-profile-in-a-django-template)