# Django: Get current user in model save

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to get the currently logged in user (`request.user`) in the `save` method of models.py. I want to check the role of the user and see if it can perform some operations based on his role.

**models.py**:

```
class TimeSheet(models.Model):
    check_in_time = models.TimeField()
    check_out_time = models.TimeField()

class Tasks(models.Model):
    time_sheet = models.ForeignKey(TimeSheet)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()

    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        project = SpentTime.objects.get(project__project__id = self.project.id)
        start = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(self.start_time), '%H:%M:%S')
        end = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(self.end_time), '%H:%M:%S')
        time = float("{0:.2f}".format((end - start).seconds/3600.0))

        if common.isDesigner(request.user):
            SpentTime.objects.filter(project__project__id = self.project.id).update(design = float(project.design) + time)

        if common.isDeveloper(request.user):
            SpentTime.objects.filter(project__project__id = self.project.id).update(develop = float(project.develop) + time)

        super(Tasks, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here the `Tasks` model is being used as inline in `Timesheet` model. I want to check the role of the currently logged in user and update another model based on the user's role. Here I need `request.user` to check the role of the current user. I am not using any forms or templates and completely making use of Django admin. Is there any method to get `request.user` in the `save` method or to check and update the values in another model in admin.py?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can tackle this problem from another angle. Instead of changing the models save method you should override the AdminSites `save_model` method. There you'll have the request object and can access the logged in user data as you already pointed out.

Have a look at this chapter of the docs: [Django ModelAdmin documentation save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model)

Comment: Thanks Jens. I tried that. Since I'm using inlines here I couldn't complete it with admin save_model. But I have completed it by adding a created_by user foreignkey field.

Comment: If you're using inlines, then you use `save_formset` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_formset

Comment: Nice one @ChrisPratt. Did'nt know this method. A few lines below there is also a method `save_related`. Maybe that'll do the trick too: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related

Comment: Right. Actually, if you're using Django 1.4, `save_related` is the way to go. Unfortunately I'm still stuck in Django 1.3.1 land, and `save_related` didn't exist yet. But, `save_formset` can still be used to accomplish the task, either way.

Comment: Note that for django 1.10, this is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model

Comment: This only seems to work when creating an object from admin. Any way to make it work  from any view?

Comment: Hey, if I override that and I have a custom save view, I should implement that logic there seperately too right?

Comment: [django-crum](https://django-crum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a middleware exactly for this.

Answer (score 28):

I found a way to do that, it involves declaring a MiddleWare, though. Create a file called `get_username.py` inside your app, with this content:

```
from threading import current_thread

_requests = {}

def get_username():
    t = current_thread()
    if t not in _requests:
         return None
    return _requests[t]

class RequestMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        _requests[current_thread()] = request
```

Edit your `settings.py` and add it to the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'yourapp.get_username.RequestMiddleware',
)
```

Now, in your `save()` method, you can get the current username like this:

```
from get_username import get_username

...

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    req = get_username()
    print "Your username is: %s" % (req.user)
```

Comment: It may create memory issue over the period of time if threads are being killed and being created again and again. You should actually add 

current_thread().user = user

and should access the property in that manner. Once the thread will be killed, memory will be released as well.

Comment: Hrishabh Gupta => if you have a better and complete answer then why don't you write it in full? This empty comment didn't help me at all, it only caused more doubts.

Comment: Error in Django 4: RequestMiddleware() takes no arguments. Edit: Adding MiddlewareMixin fixes this

Answer (score 12):

The solution proposed by @nKn is good starting point, but when I tried to implemented today, I faced two issues:

1. In the current Django version middleware created as plain object doesn't work.
2. Unittests are failing (since they usually run in single thread, so your 'request' will can be sticked between two consequent tests if the first test has HTTP-request and the second hasn't).

Here is my updated middleware code, which works with Django 1.10 and doesn't break unittests:

```
from threading import current_thread

from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


_requests = {}


def current_request():
    return _requests.get(current_thread().ident, None)


class RequestMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_request(self, request):
        _requests[current_thread().ident] = request

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        # when response is ready, request should be flushed
        _requests.pop(current_thread().ident, None)
        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        # if an exception has happened, request should be flushed too
         _requests.pop(current_thread().ident, None)
```

Comment: Do you have an example for your test? In my test always comes AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'? Thanks!

Comment: @Sascha Rau unfortunately, only tests from my commercial code, with some cohesion to my project structure.

The behavior you describe is totally OK if you try to reach request in the code where the request wasn't actually made. To be safe, try somethins like ```request = current_request() ; if request is not None: ...```

Answer (score 8):

The correct way is to use `threading.local`, instead of using a dictionary with `threading.current_thread`, since it will lead to a memory leak, since the old values will stay there for as long the application is running:

```
import threading

request_local = threading.local()

def get_request():
    return getattr(request_local, 'request', None)

class RequestMiddleware():
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        request_local.request = request
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        request_local.request = None

    def process_template_response(self, request, response):
        request_local.request = None
        return response
```

If you want to access the user instead of the request, you can do `get_request().user`, or save the user instead of the request on `__call__`

Comment: Shall this middleware be as soon or as last as possible in the list? Or it does not matter at all?

Comment: @karlosss it doesn't really matters, since you already have access to the `request` object inside of middlewares, so you won't use `get_request` there, and it doesn't modifies requests

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that save_model method override is the best option. Imagine, for instance, that you want to save the user info or validate the model based on user info and that save() does not come from a view or the adminsite itself.

What people are asking are constructions like those one:

```
def save(..)
    self.user = current_user()
```

or

```
def save(..)
    user = current_user()
    if user.group == 'XPTO':
        error('This user cannot edit this record')
```

The best approach I found so far is:

https://bitbucket.org/q/django-current-user/overview

Comment: Your link isn't working..

Comment: Indeed Ayemun. It was 10 years ago. Best solution now is https://django-crum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using the following library:

https://pypi.org/project/django-currentuser/

Snippet of how it is used from the website:

```
from django_currentuser.middleware import (get_current_user, get_current_authenticated_user)
# As model field:
from django_currentuser.db.models import CurrentUserField
class Foo(models.Model):
    created_by = CurrentUserField()
```

Comment: It doesn't work for django version 4 onwards, at least not as of today.