# How to get current user in custom methods in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

So, I have this code

```
class PostAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    def display_confirm_button(self, obj):
        # some code
    # ...
```

How to get current user in display_confirm_button method?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10993961/4117381 and this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model

Comment: @AhmedHosny those links seem to be irrelevant; they are talking about using the request in saving the model, which is not at all what OP was asking.

Comment: @AhmedHosny i need to get user without saving

Comment: You only have access to the `display_confirm_button` object in that method. You can't access the request, so you can't access the user. If you explain where you are trying to use the `display_confirm_button` method, there might be another way to solve your problem.

Comment: @Aleksey Sergeev And you can use request in other methods, check the second link

Comment: @Alasdair perhaps, this is not better solution(in deleted answer), but I wrote a simple test to check the correctness this, in `__init__` I wrote - `self.some = 0` and in `get_queryset` - `self.some += 1`, and in different requests it always 1.

Comment: I tested using `runserver`, and got a different result - `self.some` increases with each request for me. As I said in my previous comment, there might be a way to avoid using hacks like setting `self.request` or using thread locals. However, you haven't said what you're trying to do with your `display_confirm_button` method, so I can't tell.

Comment: @Alasdair so, in `display_confirm_button(self, obj)` I render(in template) a html button, which should be visible only for some users, for this I need user from request(for template context).

Comment: How do you access `display_confirm_button` in your template?

Comment: @Alasdair `load=loader.get_template('template.html')` and `display_confirm_button` return `load.render(context)`.

Comment: That's the code *in* `display_confirm_button`. What is the code that *calls* `display_confirm_button`? For example, do you include it in `list_display`?

Comment: @Alasdair of course it in `list_display`

Comment: It's not obvious, otherwise I wouldn't have asked ;)

Comment: Anyway, I think you can get the result you want by overriding `get_list_display`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class PostAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    def display_confirm_button(self, obj):
        # some code
    # ...
```

To access the logged in user, you need access to the request object. It isn't possible to access the request in your `display_confirm_button` method, since you only have access to `obj`, the object that is being edited.

The solution is to override `get_list_display`, which has access to the `request` object. You can then define your `display_confirm_button` *inside* get_list_display where it has access to the request, and include the `display_confirm_button` callable in the list that you return.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_list_display(self, request):

        def display_confirm_button(obj):
            out = logic_that_requires_user(request.user)
            return out

        return ['field1', 'field2', display_confirm_button, ...]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution IMHO is to store the current user in `changelist_view` to have it accessible in your method.

```py
class PostAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        setattr(self, 'user', request.user)
        return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context)

    def display_confirm_button(self, obj):
        # you can use self.user here
```

You can keep this DRY by creating a mixin like this:

```py
class CurrentUserMixin(object):
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        setattr(self, 'user', request.user)
        return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context)


class PostAdmin(CurrentUserMixin, models.ModelAdmin):
    def display_confirm_button(self, obj):
        # you have self.user here
```