# Django : save the user that has created the object instance

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model Package with a field owner that should contain the user ID that has created the object instance.
I thought about overriding the save() method but I didn't figure out how to get the logged in user.
I have proceeded this way

```
class Package(models.Model):
    source = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_estimation = models.DateTimeField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='packages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #WAHT TO DO HERE ?
        super(Package, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

How can I save the current logged in user ? Thank you

Comment: Check out this link and see if it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477319/in-django-how-do-i-know-the-currently-logged-in-user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is recommended save the user in the views with `Package.owner = request.User` but if you want to use it in save method [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991460/django-get-current-user-in-model-save)

Comment: I solved this by saving the user in the views, thanks for your help :)