# How to get the currently logged in user's id in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication, userid

How to get the currently logged-in user's id?

In `models.py`:

```
class Game(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='game_user', verbose_name='Owner')
```

In `views.py`:

```
gta = Game.objects.create(name="gta", owner=?)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Django, how do I know the currently logged-in user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477319/in-django-how-do-i-know-the-currently-logged-in-user)

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心法轮功六四事件 Exact Duplicate

Answer (score 314, accepted):

First make sure you have `SessionMiddleware` and `AuthenticationMiddleware` middlewares added to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting.

The current `user` is in `request` object, you can get it by:

```
def sample_view(request):
    current_user = request.user
    print current_user.id
```

`request.user` will give you a `User` object representing the currently logged-in user. If a user isn't currently logged in, `request.user` will be set to an instance of `AnonymousUser`. You can tell them apart with the field `is_authenticated`, like so:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    # Do something for authenticated users.
else:
    # Do something for anonymous users.
```

Comment: Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests

Comment: What if we want to set the foreign key userid to a model which is the currently logged in user's id?

Comment: You no longer need to update the settings. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests

Comment: Where is request coming from?

Comment: Link to [`User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/) reference.

Comment: Note **Django 1.10+** use boolean **user.is_authenticated** instead of **user.is_authenticated()**

Answer (score 30):

You can access Current logged in user by using the following code:

```
request.user.id
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you are referring to Django's [Auth User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#users), in your view:

```
def game(request):
  user = request.user

  gta = Game.objects.create(name="gta", owner=user)
```

Answer (score 2):

***FROM WITHIN THE TEMPLATES***

This is how I usually get current logged in user and their id in my templates.

```
<p>Your Username is : {{user}} </p>
<p>Your User Id is  : {{user.id}} </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually get current logged in user and their id in my templates.

```
<p>Your Username is : {{user|default: Unknown}} </p>
<p>Your User Id is  : {{user.id|default: Unknown}} </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go on your profile.html template and add a HTML tag named paragraph there,

```
<p>User-ID: {% user.id %}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HttpRequest.user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) and [get_user(request)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/auth/#utility-functions) to get the id of the logged-in user in Django Views as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import get_user # Here

def test(request):
    print(request.user.id) # 32
    print(get_user(request).id) # 32
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

And, you can get the id of the logged-in user in Django Templates as shown below:

```
{% "index.html" %}

{{ user.id }} {% 32 %}
```