# In django, how can I link a model with a user. I'd like the user to add information about their company website and name

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want the users, once they are logged in, to be able to add information about their company including website, name, logo, etc.

I already have this model

```
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, unique=True)
comp_name = models.CharField(max_length=120,default='', blank=True)
comp_site = models.URLField(default='', blank=True)
comp_logo = models.ImageField(default='', blank=True, upload_to='img/logos/')
```

in my views.py I have this:

```
if form1.is_valid():
    saveInfo = form1.save(commit=False)
    comp_name = form1.cleaned_data.get("comp_name")
    comp_site = form1.cleaned_data.get("comp_site")
    comp_logo = form1.cleaned_data.get("comp_logo")
    saveInfo.user = form1.user
    saveInfo.save()
    return redirect('/profil/')
```

What I'd like is that the program would automatically detects which user is currently logged in, and set the user field to that user.

How could I do this?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12615192/426790) for a similar question (how to get the currently logged in user).

Comment: `saveInfo.user = request.user` ?

Comment: Thanks Jedi, That was exactly it. I had done that and forgot about it so thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `request` attribute sent with any Django specifies the current user.

```
def myview(request):
    current_user = request.user
```

You can check if the user is logged in using the `request.user.is_authenticated()` method. What I would do here is redirect the login view to the view with your form. This should automatically happen if you are using `@login_required` on the form view.

As an aside, if you are extending the User model, you should use `OneToOneField` instead of `ForiegnKey`. Use `ForiegnKey`only if each user can have multiple companies.

Answer (score 0):

```
if form1.is_valid():
    saveInfo = form1.save(commit=False)
    comp_name = form1.cleaned_data.get("comp_name")
    comp_site = form1.cleaned_data.get("comp_site")
    comp_logo = form1.cleaned_data.get("comp_logo")
    saveInfo.user = request.user #<--- the authenticated user bound to the current request
    saveInfo.save()
    return redirect('/profil/')
```

`request.user` is the current user who is bound to the current request. You must (probably you already do) check if user is authenticated etc..

Comment: Yes the function has a @login_required() before it so that should be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can associate the users to a model using one to one field as shown below

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField()
    organisation = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="")
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    display_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="authors/profile", default="")
```

You can then get their info of user using 'Profile' and 'User'