# How I get User ID if logged in Django?

Tags: python, django

I need to get User ID inside from my code (not in Django template).

I've success in template, but not inside the App.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the currently logged in user's user id in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615154/how-to-get-the-currently-logged-in-users-user-id-in-django)

Answer (score 2):

here is how you can get a logged in user id in your view:

```
def user_id(request):
    user = request.user
    print user.id
```

Comment: It works, but how I get the INT result? Because, I get:
<function user_id at 0x105afd620>

Answer (score 0):

You can get current logged in user id by

```
request.user.id
```