# Django- why inbuilt auth login function not passing info about user to after successful login url

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-login

Hi I used the django inbult auth urls and views for my project and now have finished the initial user account creation/login/reset password process.

Now, the user can log in and be redirected to the after successful login url accounts/profile/.

I have several doubts on the django login function. For convenience, I've copy paste the django inbuilt login function code below.

```
@sensitive_post_parameters()
@csrf_protect
@never_cache
def login(request, template_name='registration/login.html',
          redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
          authentication_form=AuthenticationForm,
          current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    """
    Displays the login form and handles the login action.
    """
    redirect_to = request.REQUEST.get(redirect_field_name, '')

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = authentication_form(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            # Ensure the user-originating redirection url is safe.
            if not is_safe_url(url=redirect_to, host=request.get_host()):
                redirect_to = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

            # Okay, security check complete. Log the user in.
            auth_login(request, form.get_user())

            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
    else:
        form = authentication_form(request)

    current_site = get_current_site(request)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        redirect_field_name: redirect_to,
        'site': current_site,
        'site_name': current_site.name,
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                            current_app=current_app)
```

My questions are:

**1 Is the `REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME` in the function set as '/profile/' in `django.contrib.auth` ?**

I could see this variable is imported from `django.contrib.auth`

```
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login as auth_login, logout as auth_logout, get_user_model
```

I don't have any setting for this variable, but after user successfully logged in, the page will be directed to /accounts/profile/

**2  Has the login function passed the account info about the user? If yes, how can I access it?**

From the code, if user successfully logged in, page will be redirected: `return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)`

in my case, redirected to accounts/profile/ , initially the view for the url was simply a

```
HttpResponse("You have logged in successfully")
```

now when I am trying to implement the view function, I realize that no info about the user has been passed.

I've tried to `print request` in the view function, but there is no info about the user in the message printed in the server terminal, all I get is a long list of system settings or other info. However, the login should pass the info of who has just successfully logged in to the successful log in urls right?

Thank you very much for explaining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the login, you can access the user info by referring `request.user` in views and just `{{user}}` in templates. All you need to make sure is you're passing the [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) in the `HttpResponse` for the future request.

Yes, `REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME` is defined in [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L12) of django.contrib.auth which is simply a `"next"` what you passed from the login form.

In Django, there are more than one ways to force a user to login. By decorating a view function with `@login_required`, by calling the build-in login view for an user defined URL and etc., Refer about the login settings variables [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url). You'll get some more ideas.

[Building custom login page](http://www.fir3net.com/Django/django.html). That link gives you an example for custom login implementaion. Consider you have decorated a view with `@login_required` and it's corresponding URL is `/login_test/`. Then the `{{next}}` context variable in the login form will be rendered with `/login_test/`. So after you login,

`<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />`

This element's value will be taken for redirecting as per the `REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME`. Though I suspect that that example is missing the setting of `settings.LOGIN_URL` to the URL `login/`. Never mind, it's being passed as an argument in the decorator itself.

Comment: hi Babu, thank you for answering my question. Now I understand the answer to my second question now. For my first question,yea, I could see that the REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME is set to 'next' in the file now. what do you mean by the 'login form'? I didn't touch the forms nor pass in any information..

Comment: Hi now I got the answers to my question.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

To override this behavior just put following in `settings.py` of your app :

`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"`

This will redirect to your home page. You can change this url to preferred url.

Answer (score 1):

Once the user is redirected to accounts/profile/ the view for that link will be returned. You can access information about the currently logged in user there as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477319/in-django-how-do-i-know-the-currently-logged-in-user) by using `request.user`. Also tip to see what information you have access to in your views. Use `import pbd; pdb.set_trace()`. This pops you into a python prompt with access to all of the current variables. To see all the defined variables call `locals()`, though this will print out a ton of junk along with it. In the template you can [display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713077/get-user-information-in-django-templates) a "you can't access this page" message if the user isn't logged in.