# Passing 'redirect_field_name' in urls.py not taking effect

Tags: python, django

In [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) of the Django documentation, it says that passing in `redirect_field_name` via the url conf, as in

`url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'redirect_field_name': '/albums/all/'}),")`

should override the `next` value, which is where it goes after a successful login (it's stated between the two green boxes).

Mine keeps going to the default (`settings.LOGIN_URL`, which is `"/accounts/profile/"`, and I don't understand why.

Printing `next` in the login template results in the empty string: `<P>next={{ next }}</P>`

Temporarily giving up on this, I eliminated the `{'redirect_field_name', ...` from that line in `urls.py`, and instead changed `LOGIN_URL` in `settings.py` to `/albums/all/`. I restarted the server, yet it's *still* going to `/accounts/login`.

I see this question, but there's no reference to urls.py: *[Django- why inbuilt auth login function not passing info about user to after successful login url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461802/django-why-inbuilt-auth-login-function-not-passing-info-about-user-to-after-suc)*

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand from the documentation, `redirect_field_name` is used as a key to GET, where the value is the url to redirect to. Looking at the source [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fd23c06023a0585ee743c0752dc94da66694cf63/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L32) also suggests the same. If this is the case `redirect_field_name` shouldn't be set to a url. According to the documentation for `login_required` further up in the link you sent, next is passed to the view in the query string. Try passing in the url you wish to redirect to there.

Comment: Thank you for the help @crhodes. I don't understand how you mean to pass in this url to the view. How else to do it, except via its line in `urls.py`? This is how the documentation says to pass in the `template_name` parameter to the views.login() function (as in the source code you linked to): `(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'myapp/login.html'}),`. Since another parameter in that same function is `redirect_field_name`, I thought using the same method of passing would work, but obviously it doesn't. Can you please elaborate on what your suggesting?

Comment: From what I understand there are two options, either you specify the url in the querystring like so: `?next=/albums/all/`. Or, you specify a `redirect_field_name` and customize the login template as the docs note: `Note that if you provide a value to redirect_field_name, you will most likely need to customize your login template as well, since the template context variable which stores the redirect path will use the value of redirect_field_name as its key rather than "next"`

Comment: I understand the manually adding `?next=...` to the url. I don't know how to "specify a `redirect_field_name`" As far as customizing the template, I can only guess that it means changing `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ name }}" />` to `...name="next" value="{{ redirect_field_name }}" />`. If you would be willing to continue this in chat, it would be helpful.

Comment: If you change the `redirect_field_name` the template would change as you suggested. However I believe it would be `input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="/albums/all/" />`. If you look at the source I linked the `redirect_to` variable storing the url is first checked for in the POST to see if the `redirect_field_name` is there, otherwise it falls back on the GET and the url being in the querystring.

Comment: Oh! It's a *name*. I don't care about the name! I want the *value* to be `/albums/all/`. Right? Well that certainly clears things up a bit. So I could just forget about this `redirect_field_name` variable entirely, and just hard-code the value right into the template. That doesn't seem like "the right way" to do it, but it's a step in the right direction. (I wrote `name="next" value="{{ name }}"/>` in my previous comment, should be `value="{{ next }}"`). Let me give it a try!

Comment: This works: `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="/albums/all/" />` Thank you for the helping me through this, @crhodes. I've been banging my head on this for four hours. PHEW.