# Automatically fill a field with the name of the user that creates the object?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model, `Package`:

```
class Package(models.Model):
    VIP = models.BooleanField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contents = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = # username that created this object
```

Whenever a user adds a new `Package` (through admin), I want that the `owner` to contain the name of this user. How can I do this?

Comment: This is too vague. How is the `Package` added? Through form? Through admin?

Comment: We need more info on a couple of items: (1.) where are you creating it (as Shang Wang said)? (2.) What kind of user? Another model of yours? Subclass of `auth.User`? Some 3rd party package's user model?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Django, how do I know the currently logged-in user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477319/in-django-how-do-i-know-the-currently-logged-in-user)

Comment: If you create the object in a view, you could take the user from the request.

Comment: @ShangWang through admin.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide the owner field in the admin, then exclude the owner field from the model admin, and set the owner in the [`save_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method.

```
class PackageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('owner',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            # only set owner when object is first created
            obj.owner = request.user
        obj.save()
```

If you want to keep the form's owner field, then override [`get_changeform_initial_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_changeform_initial_data), and add the owner as an initial value.

```
class PackageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
        return {'owner': request.user}
```

The code above assumes that owner is a foreign key to the user model, which is the approach I recommend. If you really want to store the username as a string, then you need to change the lines above to:

```
obj.owner = request.user.username

return {'owner': request.user.username}
```

Comment: This is a solution. But I don't want to hide the `owner` field from the admin. Instead, I would like that the default value be the user creating the object for the first time. Is there a way to do this? *Please, if you find a way to do this, don't delete the previous answer, as it is useful too*.

Comment: I've added an alternative approach that keeps the owner form field.

Comment: The `get_form` gives me an error: `modelform_factory() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'`. Have you tested this? I am using django 1.7

Comment: No, I haven't tested the code. I've updated the answer, try overriding `get_changeform_initial_data` instead.