# Django Login With Templates and MySql

Tags: mysql, ajax, django, authentication

I am a beginner with Django and I need some help creating a login with templates to connect it with the MySql database.

I have written a model through Inspectdb command and the template also.
I need help with writing views for login and register so that data can be matched with and stored in the database.

```
from django.shortcuts import render    
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate    
import myapp.models    
from django.http import HttpResponse  

def hello(request):

   return render(request, "login.html", {})

def mylogin(request):  
    if request.POST:  
    username = request.POST.get('username')  
    password = request.POST.get('password')  

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    print 1
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        print username
    # success
        return render(request, 'index.html')
    else:
  # invalid login
        return render(request, 'login.html')
else:
    return render (request,'login.html')

def mylogout(request):
  logout(request)
  return direct_to_template(request, 'logged_out.html')
```

I am writing this in my view with model written I still cannot authenticate a user.
User is the model function which was generated through DB Mysql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login code for Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476596/login-code-for-django)

Comment: @Nanhydrin I am still facing problems, I have my model written.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? You say you can't authenticate, how do you know, what are you seeing? I'm not going to be able to answer your question, but I can help you improve it so maybe someone else can.

Comment: @Nanhydrin There are no errors but I used print statement also in inside if parts and when it is not reaching there then how will it authenticate..

Comment: Django documentation says the format of the command for getting the details from the request is `username = request.POST['username']` whereas you've got a `.get` after the POST. Have you tried this already?

Comment: @Nanhydrin I tried it also..!! But it is not going inside that If user is not None block

Answer (score 0):

okay, I can't add comment but here are some tips you can check :
first, check your setting.py is properly configured for authenticate and login
then, maybe you should print username or user before testing "if user is not None"
moreover, maybe you should check the default value of the redirection after your login and add login in your import
I can help you I did it and its working fine so do not hesitate to ask more questions and really give more details about what you want and what erreor you've got.
Hope this will help you.